# Use Virtual Machine as Proxy in VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, proxy

I would like to network 3 VMs in VirtualBox. One will be running a proxy. Two will be unable to connect to the Internet directly, but be able to connect through the proxy VM. How should I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to setup the machine that will be hosting the proxy with two network adapters.  One adapter should be [bridged](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_bridged) (or NAT) and will provide access to the internet.  The other adapter should be configured as part of an [internal network](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_internal).  The other machines should also be configured to be  part of the same internal network.  You may want to use VirtualBox's [built in DHCP server](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#vboxmanage-dhcpserver) on the internal network to make IP configuration easier.

Once the machines are all setup, you'll need to configure the two other machine's proxy settings to point to the proxy machine's internal network IP.